# PyQt widgets in multiple files

Tags: python, pyqt

i'd like to learn PyQt by writing a simple game.  the first widget would have buttons like "New game", "Quit", etc.  i am having trouble understanding how to transition from that menu widget to a new one.

for instance, if i were to click New Game, how do i have a new widget appear that replaces the old one and asks for the user's name?  the way i am approaching it now is something like

```
Form = QtGui.QWidget()
ui = uiMainMenu()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()
```

then once newGameButton is pressed it would go to a subroutine...

```
Form2 = QtGui.QWidget()
ui2 = uiNewGame()
ui2.setupUi(Form2)
Form2.show()
```

i'm not asking for all the code, just an explanation as to how i should be approaching the problem, because the code above ain't doing squat.
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to switch between forms then you can use QStackedWidget.
Below you can find a working sample code:

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class Form1(QWidget):
    showForm2Signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.newGameButton = QPushButton("New Game", self)
        self.quitButton = QPushButton("Quit", self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("<html>My Game<br>Start Page</html>"))
        layout.addWidget(self.newGameButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.quitButton)
        self.newGameButton.clicked.connect(self.showForm2Signal.emit)
        self.quitButton.clicked.connect(qApp.quit)


class Form2(QWidget):
    showForm1Signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.backButton = QPushButton("Back", self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("New Game Started!"))
        layout.addWidget(self.backButton)
        self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.showForm1Signal.emit)


class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.stack = QStackedWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.stack)
        self.form1 = Form1(self)
        self.form2 = Form2(self)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.form1)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.form2)
        self.form1.showForm2Signal.connect(partial(self.stack.setCurrentWidget,
                                               self.form2))
        self.form2.showForm1Signal.connect(partial(self.stack.setCurrentWidget,
                                               self.form1))
        self.stack.setCurrentWidget(self.form1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit()
```

If you only want to ask the name to the user then you can use a QDialog widget.